# Kafka produce to send image

Tags: java, image, apache-kafka

I have the following Kafka producer code. I want to know if I can send image file instead of JSON file? Is there any code reference sending an image file through Kafka producer?

```
    try {           
                URL url = getClass().getResource("test.json");
                File file = new File(url.getPath());
                Properties props = new Properties();            
                props.put("bootstrap.servers", "yupsectory.selet.com:9092");
                props.put("client.id", CLIENT_ID);
                props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
                props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
                String jsonData = readFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);    
                System.out.println("jarr: " + jobj.getJSONObject("data").toString());    

                Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer <>(props);      
                //Use this util to pull the context that needs to be propagated from the HttpServletRequest
                Map<String, String> headermap = YupsectoryContextUtil.buildContextMap(request);
                //Sending a message
                ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, jobj.getJSONObject("data").toString());
                producer.send(record, headermap);           
                producer.close();                 
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: what do you want exactly ? did you try and do you have any issue?

Comment: For starters, you would not use any JSON classes or a String for an image file... You would send bytes, and use the ByteArraySerializer... So you should instead ask or search for "how to get bytes of an image file in Java"

Answer (score 2):

Image can be sent as byte array in message value. so your code will be changed as given.

```
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send an image by following these simple steps:

1) convert your image into bytes array ( by search for "how to get bytes of an image file )

2) change this line from :-

```
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

to:-

```
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
```

3) give your bytesarray of your image file

and, you are good to go.